# Encoding in Python toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox, encoding, pandas

My Python toolbox uses a function (code below) to save values to a CSV file. When I was using the same code in a Jupyter notebook, saved records were properly encoded (I am dealing with Polish letters like ć,ą,ę), but when I run my code in ArcGIS Pro as a toolbox script I got results such as BiaĹ‚ostocka instead of Białostocka saved in the CSV.

I tried adding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But without any positive results.

Code for function below:

```
def zapis_do_csv(
        lista_1, lista_2, nazwa_1, 
        nazwa_2, csv_name, katalog, 
        czesc_nazwy):

raw_data = {nazwa_1: lista_1,
            nazwa_2: lista_2}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=[nazwa_1, nazwa_2])
df.to_csv('{0}\{1}_{2}.csv'.format(katalog, czesc_nazwy, csv_name), index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Just a note: what you tried adding is just a comment and has no actual commands. Maybe you could try searching for how to set the default encoding programmatcally.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156012/dataframe-encoding

Comment: Great, glad to help. You should write what worked as a short answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encoding = 'CP1250' did the trick

**Below my fixed code:**

```
df.to_csv('{0}\{1}_{2}.csv'.format(katalog, czesc_nazwy, csv_name), index=False, header=True, encoding = 'CP1250')
```